# Submitting multiple variables with one input

Tags: php, jquery, input, radio-button

```
foreach($rates as $item){    
    if ($item->disabled == false){
        echo '<input type="radio" name="rate" id="membership" required="yes" message="Please select your membership type."  value="' . $item->rate . '"><input type="hidden" name="membership" value="' . $item->membership . '" >';
    }
}
```

This is probably pretty simple, but the issue that I'm having is that I can't get $item->membership to submit with $item->rate. For example when somebody selects the '125' rate, it should also submit 'Student' or whatever. When I do submit the form though, it submits the last $item->membership in the series instead of the one that is tied to it's rate... Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure I'm overthinking this.

Thanks

Comment: All your hidden inputs will have the same name of `membership`. That's fine for a radio button, but not for other types of input.

Comment: What would the appropriate way be to submit $item->rate with the correct $item->membership then?

Comment: best way is to get the `membership` against the posted `rate` do not try to get in hidden field user can change the data of fields

Comment: @AustinSlominski - you could name the hidden field  as `'membership_' . $item->rate`, which means you'd be able to work out which field to use based on the `rate` submitted. But as dianuj says - it's probably best not to rely on the correct amount being passed back from the form, in case it's been altered. It's a little bit more work, but it's more secure to take the submitted rate and query the database again to get the right amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they all have the same name attribute, so they set the same variable multiple times and thus the last one is what you always get. Try giving all the hidden inputs unique names, so you can get the membership you want. HTML forms aren't smart enough to pick only the hidden input next to the radio button, they all get posted.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit an form, hidden field and radio button are independent elements regardless how you wrap them together.

Here is my solution to pass multiple variables for each radio button

view:

```
<form method="post" action="your_post_file.php" >
    <?php $i = 1;  foreach($rates as $item){?>
        <input type="radio" name="rates[]" value="<?php echo $i?>" /><?php echo $item->rate?>
        <input type="hidden" name="rate<?php echo $i?>" value="<?php echo $item->rate?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="membership<?php echo $i?>" value="<?php echo $item->member_id?>" />
    <?php $i++;}?>

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

on the your_post_file.php

```
if(isset($_POST['rates'])){
            if(is_array($_POST['rates'])){

                $index = $_POST['rates'][0]; //return the index of selected radio button

                $rate =  $_POST['rate' . $index];
                $membership_id =  $_POST['membership' . $index];

                //print out the result
                var_dump($rate);
                var_dump($membership_id);

            }
        }
```

Bingo, you get what you want, even you want more the value for each rate, just add more hidden field with same given format, such as first name, last name, or anything else.